# Is MSAL correct for this case?

Tags: azure-ad-msal

I have an old web app that uses Forms Authentication that we've converted to support SAML using Shibboleth. This part is complete and works fine. The app redirects to login.microsoftonline.com, allows a login against the customer's AD (hburg.kyschools.us), and redirects back to the app which now allows the authenticated user in.

The web app also has some ASP.NET Web API controllers that we'd like to authenticate the same way. This also seems to work when the controllers are accessed from a browser that has already logged in. So far, so good.

Now we want to access these Web API controllers from a WPF app. The WPF app has been accessing them for years but just using Basic Authentication. Looking for an example, I found this project on github that shows how to use MSAL:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-desktop-msgraph-v2

This project will acquire a token via MSAL and then use it with HttpClient to call a web service. I can run this project and use it to log in to the same AD as above (hburg.kyschools.us). And then it can use HttpClient to access MS Graph.

Now, when instead I try to have the project call into my Web API controller using HttpClient, passing in the same token I received back from the hburg.kyschools.us AD, I get back the Log In page at login.microsoftonline.com, as if I haven't authenticated.

Can I use MSAL to get a token this way that can be used to access my web api via HttpClient from WPF? It seems like I'd need to tell MSAL that I want the token to include authorization for the web app. Is that done somehow in the scopes parameter?